# Locating "Bankhead of ..." in parish of Forfar

Tags: palaeography, 18th-century, scotland, parish-register, scotlands-people

I am attempting to determine the location of an area whose name is difficult to read on two parish records from the parish of Forfar:

The marriage of John Ormond and Katherine Henderson in 1767 (bottom of the record)

> "John Ormond weaver in Bankhead of T...ng and Katherine Henderson dau.
>   to Ja.s Henderson farmer in Auchterforfar ... "

[image]

The birth of Charles Ormond to the above parents in 1776 (top of the record):

> "John Ormond weaver in Bankhead of T...ing & Katherine Henderson his
>   spouse had their child's name registered called Charles, being born
>   and baptized this day."

[image: Baptism of Charles Ormond 1776]

I have looked through lists of the hamlets in the parish of Forfar during this time and haven't been able to find a place name that looks correct. There is a place called Tealing in Angus but it had its own church at the time and thus it seems implausible and there doesn't seem to be a place called "Bankhead of Tealing".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be:

> "Bankhead of Turfbeg"

*Turfbeg* is a district to the north-east of the modern town, in roughly the same place as "Bankhead" on this snippet from an [1850 map](https://maps.nls.uk/view/74401106) by James Knox:

[image: Forfar and Bankhead]

Bankhead and Turfbeg can be seen in rather better detail in this snippet from the [1861 Ordnance survey map of Forfar](https://maps.nls.uk/view/74426916):

[image: Snippet from 1861 Ordnance Survey map of Forfar]

Comment: Well spotted. On one of my odd places I had to go through I can't remember how many maps in the NLS site. The one that had the name was quite a bit older than the reference as well. Just a name that was remembered by some, I guess. But the NLS site is definitely the place to go.

Comment: Great spot. Thanks